# Missing method set_RenderOnUIThread

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xna-4.0, monogame

I'm making a C# game using Visual C# Studio 2013 Express with Mono-game.

when i debug my solution i am getting errors on following lines:

```
 public class Game1 : Game
{
    public SpriteBatch SpriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        var graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
        graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft | DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
    }// and more...
```

> Error  ( 3081): Missing method OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGameView::set_RenderOnUIThread(bool) in assembly OpenTK-1.0.dll, referenced in assembly /data/data/Game1.Game1/files/.**override**/MonoGame.Framework.dll

An unhandled exception occured.

Help me please.

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug? It is clearly says, it is a **read**-only.

Comment: how can i fix this error?